# Spring RestTemplate Post Issue

Tags: spring, resttemplate

While trying to post using Spring Rest Template, am facing the below issue,

Below is my code,

**Configuration**

```
            @Bean
            @Qualifier("restService")
            public RestTemplate createRestTemplate(
                    @Value("${profileRetreival.client.readTimeoutMillis}") Integer maxReadTimeOut,
                    @Value("${profileRetreival.client.connectionTimeoutMillis}") Integer maxTimeOut) {

                HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                        httpClient());
                clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(maxTimeOut);
                clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(maxReadTimeOut);

                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);

                restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestResponseErrorHandler());
                //restTemplate.setMessageConverters(createMessageConverters());

                return restTemplate;
            }
```

**The Restemplate class**

```
public HttpHeaders prepareheaders() {
                    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.add(CONSUMER, "*****");
                    headers.add(CLIENT, "*******");
                    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                    return headers;
            }



        HttpEntity<String> request= new HttpEntity<>( req.toString(), prepareheaders() );

        ResponseEntity<FooData> response = restClient.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, FooData.class);

        System.err.println(response.getBody()
```

The above code works fine.
But if i add the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to the configuation step, am getting an error from the service

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        jsonMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(getObjectMapper());
        messageConverters.add(jsonMessageConverter);

        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(createMessageConverters());
```

And post like below,

```
 FooData response = restClient.postForObject(url, request, FooData.class);

            System.err.println(response)
```

This causes a 500 status code, internal server error

Please can someone point me if i am doing something wrong or the correct way to do it. Is jackson converter a unwanted addition for unmarshalling as Spring does that

Comment: Any particular error?  That kinda matters...  "Fix the problem with my car!"
  "What problem?"
  "YES!"

Comment: updated the question. Results in 500 internal server error

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Only 500 internal error

Comment: nothing in the logs?  Try turning up the logging